# Why sometimes my react functional component is not updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't understand why sometimes my react functional component props is not rerendered (following code in child ModalOrderForm is not fired) when `orderModalData` is updated inside parent.

```html
<ModalOrderForm order={orderModalData} />
```

```html
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(order)
  }, [order])
```

But following  if clause wrap fixes the problem:

```html
{orderModalData && <ModalOrderForm order={orderModalData} />}
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, indicating specifically how you are observing the problem?